# issue with multiple array calling in oop design

Tags: oop

I want to model the following situation for a student registration software. In my model I have a set of students, each student can take four courses at most and each course can have maximum three grades.

I have decided to put an schema of three arrays, like this:

```
Students[]---->Courses[]---->Grades[]
```

so that I have an array of Students, each student have an array of courses inside, and each course has an array of grades.

The issue is when I want to list the students, I will have something like:

```
for i=1 to Students.length() //read students
    for each student i read courses c
        for each courses c read grades
```

Is there any way to avoid this nesting? I am using mostly Java for coding

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a reasonable design to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an **O(n^3)** loop, it's an **O(n)** loop.  where **n** is the number of grades you have recorded.

Having 3 nexted loops doesn't mean you have **O(n^3)** unless all 3 of those loops iterate over the same `n`

Your time complexity could be said to be **O(s*c*g)** where

- **s** is the number of students
- **c** is the maximum courses per student
- **g** is the maximum grades per course.

Since **c** is capped at 4 and **g** is capped at 3, you have **O(s*4*3)** which equals **O(s)**

and that's how much data you have.

If you truly intend to process all the grades for all the students Then you'd be hard pressed to have better time complexity than you have storage complexity.

Comment: if I want to read all the students, and from each students all the courses, and from each course all the grades; does it not make it a O(n^3) algorithm?

Comment: @jma Before I answer that, what is **n** supposed to refer to in your calculation?

Comment: I mean reading the external loop (students) will take m time, for read each one of the courses is n time, and for reading each of the grades of students is k time. So we will have O(m*n*k), simplifying O(n^3)

Comment: **O(m*n*k)** can only be **O(n^3)** when both **m** and **k** are **O(n)**

Comment: @jma it is no more O(n^3) than keeping all the grades in one list and iterating over that list would be.

Comment: let's call your top level n, so let's say number of students is n.  Students can have maximum of 4 courses, and a maximum of 12 grades (3 * 4 courses).  looping through all the student's is O(n*4*3) = O(n*12) = O(n)